# Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console while trying to open filestructure of laravel using terminal

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I installed laravel 5.2 and tying to open the file structure through terminal using command: `open .`, it comes with error

> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.

How can I resolve this problem? Currently I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIZMk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
gnome-open .
```

It should work in Ubuntu.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-open-gnome-nautilus-file-manager/

Comment: I did but I don't have 15 reputation and the rest you know